# How to avoid the multiple path to same file in php using htaccess?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, seo

[image]My url is

```
 www.abc.com/cbn/either/index.php
```

and I want to access this by only current url. When I change the path of the 
index.php file, i.e.

```
 www.abc.com/cbn/index.php
```

Still, I am accessing index.php file which is a bad approach for SEO point of view because now google will index two URLs of the same file. So please help me out to fix this problem.

Comment: Is it the same script? Or just two files with the same name? If the 1st - how do you do so? does htaccess makes such redirect?

Comment: see the problem is i wants only one url  www.abc.com/cbn/either/index.php but if i remove ebn or either from the url i still can access the index.php file. i don't want like this

Comment: access this "trail.wheelzkart.com/car-Interior/interior-armrest/armrest1" and now remove  interior-armrest from the url. you will still get armrest1

Comment: It may be done by htaccess but rather, it is the logic of cms

Comment: do you have any idea how to do that by htaccess

Comment: i just added the screenshot of my htaccess file

Comment: This behavior is logic of cms

Comment: it showing the error when i am pasting my htaccess. so i uploaded screenshot

Comment: What do you want - redirect  301 or 404 error, when asking index.php at lower levels ?

Comment: index.php file should open on exact url(www.abc.com/cbn/either/index.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add such line in your htaccess after RewriteBase

```
RewriteRule cbn/index.php /cbn/either/index.php [R,L]
```